# dojo mixin "global" context

Tags: dojo, mixins

if I have two classes , #1 is a mixin of #2 and #1 declares properties (with default-values - e.g.: [] to declare an new, empty array) - why does it happen, that all instances of class#2 share the SAME array-instance?

do I allways have to initialize my properties in constructor?

the faulty code looks like:

```
dojo.declare("C1",
        [dojo.Stateful],
        {
            _watches:[],
            constructor:function(){
               this._watches.push("test");
            }
            ...
        }
);


dojo.declare("C2",
    [dijit.MenuBarItem,C1],
    {
        constructor:function(){
           console.debug(this._watches.length);
        }
    }
);

new C2();
new C2();
new C2();
new C2();
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because complex variables declared on the prototype are treated as "static" member variables (and hence are shared between all instances). Complex instance variables have to be declared as `this._watches = []` inside a member function.

See: http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2011/05/17/dojo-beginner-gotcha-accidental-static-fields/